# I need to stitch 1024 JPEG files together

Tags: jpeg, image-editing

I have 1024 256x256 JPEG files called Column_Row.jpg (replace words with coordinates on 32x32 grid). I need to stitch them into one big image. What is the best software I could use to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I do this routinely using the imagemagik tools.

I can't remember the exact syntax off the top of my head, i think it's the "montage" tool you use.

What you then do is loop over each column to create rows, so for example of windows:

```
for %a in (column_*.jpg) do montage -a -out row_X.jpg
```

where "row_X" is replaced with "row_1", "row_2" and so on.

then once you have all your rows

```
for %a in (row_*.jpg) do montage -a -h -out finished.jpg
```

or something like that (As I say it's been a while, since I typed it by hand)

I'm not at my usual PC at the moment, so I can't look at the batch files I normally use to give you the exact syntax, but the image magik site for the montage tool should help you:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=11320

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853334/glueing-tile-images-together-using-imagemagicks-montage-command

Comment: Your commands seem to be missing the actual file parameter (%a), and I'd guess resaving the same .jpg a thousand times would ruin it's quality...

Comment: Yes indeed, I did type it in a hurry on my mobile phone however. :-)  I'll tidy it up when I get chance.  You get the general idea though.  Mogrify will do the job quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Shawty's answer will do what you need, but in the event that your images were not appropriately numbered, you could use a tool like AutoStitch: 
http://matthewalunbrown.com/autostitch/autostitch.html

It will analyse the images and stitch them together in to one large image, cropping and joining as it goes to make one large image with the contents of all the smaller images.

I use it when I take large panorama shots with my camera, then want to stitch them all together to make one image for print.

Comment: If your looking at using Autostitch, you may also want to look at "Microsoft ICE" too.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/product/computational-photography-applications/image-composite-editor/ I use this for the same purpose as Dave Lucre uses it.  Be aware though, tools like ICE and Autostitch work better when the images have an overlap, if they have no overlap, then ICE and Autostitch will have a hard time matching things and the Mogrify method would be preferable.